# Launcher activity name as project name in android

Tags: eclipse

while importing project in my Eclipse,I am getting (Launcher activity name as project name).In Android

How can I able to get project name?

Answer (score 0):

look at the `.project` file at the root of your project

especially, `<name>` key under `<projectDescription>`

Comment: I didnt find <name> in my project.properties file

Comment: it's not `project.properties`, it's just `.project` file(hidden initially)

Comment: take a look at the [article](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fmisc%2Fproject_description_file.html)

Comment: I found this Tag,it has my application.What should I do

Comment: replace the value with desired name and import the project